# Handle loading of content then go to different scenes

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have two scenes from where the user can enter information (one is actually scanning a barcode, the other enter the number manually)

From there, I want to download information from my backend.

Depending on what I get back, I want to go to one or another scene.

Here is a sample of my storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

I don't know how to handle the loading part. My first idea was to have a scene with only a spinner and download the content from here. Once I get it I can choose to which scene I want to go to and it's done. But...

When the user clicks the "Back" button from the scenes on the right, he goes back to the "loading" scene instead of the last "logical" scene (the input scene).

So my question is two-fold:

- Do I handle the download correctly, by using a scene just for that?
- If I do it right, how do I go back to the last input scene instead of going back to the loading scene? (I found some solutions to unwind the segue, but none that use the navigation controller, which I want to use)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a scene for the loading sounds good.

As you're working in a `UINavigationController` stack here, when you're ready to trigger the segue to the next screen you should pop the loading view controller from the stack without animation, then trigger the segue:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

// now trigger the segue
```

Comment: If I do this, I get an error. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'detailsFromLoadingSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'` If I do it after triggering the segue it does not work either.

Comment: The name of the segue you're trying to use would seem to be wrong.